# Show progress for Web Worker importScripts?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I am using Web Worker to perform a heavy task (video convert), and I need to load a big JS file (23MB, 6MB gzipped) using `importScripts`.

Is there a way to show/send message the download progress (other method like jQuery are ok, as long as it works in Web Worker)?

The environment is normal web browser, not application, and our target is relatively modern Google Chrome.